# Yammer REST API - Documented Parameter not working

Tags: rest, yammer

The API documented here - http://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-users clearly states:

```
"4) Alias to /api/v1/users/current user’s id.format. Supports include_followed_users, include_followed_tags, and include_group_memberships parameters.

GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/by_email.json?email=user@domain.com`
```

Yet, when we try this, it does not return any followed user information at all! The request we're using is like so:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/by_email.json?email=me@company.com&include_followed_users=true
```

However, this request DOES return followed users, but only for the current user:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json?include_followed_users=true
```

Am I missing something completely obvious and being stupid or is there a real issue here? If this was taken out for whatever reason, then you'd have thought that the API documentation would have been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Yammer Team did eventually get back to me on this. Their response below:**
*(I've removed https://www.yammer.com from URLs because I don't have enough rep' to post more links)*

Hey Jason Dunbar looks like the documentation here is wrong.

I looked in to this and had some conversations with a few engineers this week and have the following (albeit more arduous workaround):

1) Call get user by email endpoint and retrieve the id attribute from here: /api/v1/users/by_email.json?email=user…

2) To grab following users, take that id and:

GET /api/v1/users/following/[:id].json

3) To grab group memberships for that user you'll need to impersonate him/her (verified admin only) and

GET /api/v1/users/current.json

We'll get the documentation updated ASAP with this. Also happy to keep the conversation going to help if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the `email` parameter to the user's email that they are registered with.

E.G. if your company has multiple domains but the Yammer network is under `bigco.com` and the user is registered with an email under `bigcosubsidiary.com` you'll need to make a request to the API with `user@bigcosubsidiary.com`.

Comment: I can confirm that the e-mail addresses I am attempting to use are correct. Still no followers...

Comment: @JasonDunbar yeah it looks like `include_followed_users=true` is only supported for `current.json`

Answer (score 0):

-as mentioned - it looks like its only for current.json - you can check it here http://yammer-dev.herokuapp.com/endpoints/4 - hope it helps.
Rich